# Routing Jetty http traffic to https

Tags: ssl, https, jetty

I am trying to make Jetty 8.0 secure.

I have followed all the instruction mentioned [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL).

But I am not able to redirect http requests to https. Can some one help me in this?

I do get valid response when I do https:/// but do not get any response when I do http://:9393/.

9393 is the port where the application is configured to run.

Under the heading "Redirecting http requests to https" it says

> To redirect http to https, the webapp should indicate it needs CONFIDENTIAL or INTEGRAL connections from users. This is done in web.xml:

Which web.xml they are referring to? The one which belongs to the application deployed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `web.xml` in your web application. Look at this if you haven't before: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL#Redirecting_http_requests_to_https